# Select the Nth input element in a form

Tags: javascript, forms, input

I'm looking for something like

`document.forms["form"].inputs[n].value`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
document.forms["form"].getElementsByTagName("input")[n].value
```

Comment: That is indeed: the Truth :) thanks a lot, I will accept as soon as I can